# Jquery .Hover issue with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have this code:

```
cuts_html = '';
for( i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++ ) {
    fburl3 = site_url + '/haircut-detail/?img_id=' + attachments[i].ID + '&uid=' + attachments[i].post_author;
    if( isNaN(attachments[i].view_count) ) attachments[i].view_count = 0;
        
    cuts_html += '<div id="controller-image" class="cut-image">';



    cuts_html += '<div id="cut-imageplacer">';

        

                            
    cuts_html +=    '<div class="cut-image-info">' +
                        'By <a href="' + user_profile_url + 
                        '&user_id=' + attachments[i].post_author + '">' +
                        attachments[i].author_name + '</a>' +
                        '</div>';
                            
    cuts_html +=    '<div class="commentbox-1">' +
                        '<img src="https://d2xcq4qphg1ge9.cloudfront.net/assets/17276/435546/original_views.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                        attachments[i].view_count + 
                        '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="https://d2xcq4qphg1ge9.cloudfront.net/assets/17276/435545/original_talk-bubble.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                        '<fb:comments-count href="' + fburl3 + '"></fb:comments-count>' +
                        '</div></div>';

    cuts_html +=    '<a class="cut-image-a" ' +
                        'href="' + image_detail_url + 
                        '?uid=' + attachments[i].post_author + 
                        '&img_id=' + attachments[i].ID + '">' +
                        attachments[i].attachment_image_html + '</a>';

                            
    cuts_html += '</div>';
}
```

Div Id `cut-imageplacer` is `display:none`, so what I want is when someone hovers the `controller-image` div, the `cut-imageplacer` to show and hide of course when not on. I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){    $('.cut-image').hover(
    function(){     $('#cut-imageplacer').show();
}, function () {        $('#cut-imageplacer').hide();    });  }); </script>
```

But it doesn't work... Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or point me to correct direction?

Comment: I even used  $(this).children on the div but didn't work either

Comment: where is `attachments` defined? can you include that in your code?

Comment: Hint: This can be done more easily with pure CSS

Comment: Where does your question include Ajax? Please remove that buzzword from the title and from the tags, or clarify your approach.

Comment: I am appending content using ajax... what is wrong with my title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look like you are trying to attach events to elements that are being dynamically created. You need to use `Live()` or `On()` to attach events to these elements after they are created. Look at [This](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [This](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to see how to use those.

like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){    
       $('.cut-image').live("hover",
          function(){     
              $('#cut-imageplacer').show();
          }, function () {        
              $('#cut-imageplacer').hide();    
           });  
       }); </script>
```

Comment: I tried this '<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on("hover",'.cut-image', function(){     
    $('#cut-imageplacer').show();
 }, function () {        
  $('#cut-imageplacer').hide();    
  });  
  });
</script>'